# strtok of single character

Tags: c

I must tokenize a string with this format:

```
 pippo:c:C2,C3,C4:pippo
```

how do I tokenize this string using strtok (i don't need the string once i've done the tokening anymore). I want the lone character to be stored into a char variable and not in a char* variable.

Comment: What character are you looking for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you only want the c in the :c: part, and you know that things will have this format, you don't have to go as far as tokenizing. You can simply do

```
char c = strchr(str, ':')[1];
```

This locates the first :, and gets the character following it. Of course, strtok would also work:

```
strtok(str, ":");
char c = strtok(NULL, ":")[0];
```

This fetches the second tokenized word, and get the first character of that word. In general, if you wanted things further in, you would probably want to use a loop instead. Not that the str buffer must be writeable in this case, unlike the others.

Finally, if the `pippo` part always has the same length, you can get away with simply

```
char c = str[6];
```

In all cases, `str = "pippo:c:C2,C3,C4:pippo"`.

Comment: I think you're not using strtok correctly, the inner call will return "pippo" and the outer call will return "pippo"[0] that's just 'p'

Comment: you'll need to call it at least twice. second time with NULL

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a single character between two tokens using `strtok()` you can do so by checking the string length you've extracted.

```
int main ()
{
    char str[] ="pippo:c:C2,C3,C4:pippo";
    char * pch;
    char winner;

    pch = strtok (str,":"); 
    while (pch != NULL)
    {
      if(strlen(pch) == 1){   // if there's only 1 char we got it
        winner = pch[0];      // if there's more than 1 single char of :x: format you
        break;                // could check for that too here.
      }
      pch = strtok (NULL, ":");
    }

    printf("And the winner is: %c\n", winner);
    return 0;
}
```